# Google Analytics : read clientId inside body

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I load the new Universal Analytics code in the head, and get the clientId

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-12345678-00', 'example.com');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    var clientId = '';
    ga(function (tracker) {
        clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
    });
// ]]></script>
```

In the head I also load a script to change the content of a link

```
<script>$("a#test").attr('href', ($("a#test").attr('href') + (clientId)));</script>
```

Inside the body there is the link that should get changed:

```
<a id="test" href="http://example.com?client=">test</a>
```

Unfortunately the clientId value doesn't append to the link as it should, anyone can help me ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wait for onload event of window object as GA use an ajax request, should work:

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
    $("#test").attr('href', $("#test").attr('href') + (clientId));
});
```

Comment: I was using old jquery, it works after I updated it to the latest version. Thank you!

Comment: ya. on() method is from jq 1.7